# Does peak bone density have any other role in preventing osteoporosis?

Tags: bones, osteoporosis

From reading articles such as [this](https://www.mayoclinic.org/healthy-lifestyle/fitness/in-depth/strength-training/art-20046670) I understand that over time, building your muscles to reach your peak bone density means that you may have sufficient peak bone density to cope with age-related bone loss, preventing osteoporosis in the future.

But,

It is unclear to me what is the role of peak bone mass in reducing risk of osteoporosis?

Does peak bone density have any other role in preventing osteoporosis?

Comment: Welcome to MedicalSciences.SE. For [reasons mentioned in this post](https://medicalsciences.meta.stackexchange.com/q/411) and in [ask], we require prior research information when asking questions. I have helped by adding a link to the MayoClinic on muscle building increasing bone density, but please can you help us to help you and [edit] your question to provide more information on what you have read on this subject. This helps to provide an answer which will be more helpful. If you found nothing, what did you Google?

Comment: @JohnDoea and Chris, thank you for editing. I will keep this in mind next time I ask a question on StackExchange

Comment: @Lisa thank you ; welcome,

Answer (score 1):

[Peak bone mass](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peak_bone_mass) is the maximum amount of bone a person has during their life. It typically occurs in the early 20s in females and late 20s in males. Peak bone mass is typically lower in females than males

The risk of development of osteoporosis can be minimized by understanding the development of the skeletal system and the lifestyle choices that maximize bone development.

> Bone mass and strength achieved at the end of the growth period, simply designated as "Peak Bone Mass (PBM)", plays an essential role in the risk of osteoporotic fractures occurring in adulthood. It is considered that an increase of PBM by one standard deviation would reduce the fracture risk by 50%.[Link](https://scielosp.org/article/spm/2009.v51suppl1/s5-s17/en/)

The risk of fracture is determined largely by bone density, which is the end result of peak value achieved at skeletal maturity and subsequent age- and menopause-related bone loss. The risk of osteoporotic fracture at any site relates to bone mineral density at that site and the amount of stress applied to that bone.[Link](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/8499027)

> It is commonly accepted that development of a higher peak bone mass during adolescent years protects against postmenopausal osteoporosis. There is a strong inverse relationship between bone mineral density and incidence of fracture in postmenopausal women. Bone loss in a postmenopausal woman with low peak bone density will have greater consequences for fracture than that in a woman with higher peak bone mineral density.[Link](https://academic.oup.com/jcem/article/84/6/1839/2864329)

As mentioned in [Cochrane](https://www.cochrane.org/CD000333/MUSKEL_exercise-for-preventing-and-treating-osteoporosis-in-postmenopausal-women), exercise will improve bone mineral density just slightly so it can reduce the chance of having a fracture to some extent.

Comment: Would you mind to make it even more clear that peak bone density is achieved until age 18-20? So, does exercise in adults increase bone density? I guess not much and there's one [Cochrane review](https://www.cochrane.org/CD000333/MUSKEL_exercise-for-preventing-and-treating-osteoporosis-in-postmenopausal-women) about it.

Comment: @Jan Sure. will do.